# React test with enzyme TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to do unit testing to a component using enzyme **shallow rendering**. Trying to test state activeTab of the component and it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property state`. my component Accordion. Accordion component jsx code

```
 class Accordion extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            activeTab: 0
        }
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        tabs: [{title: 'Status'}, {title: 'Movement'}]
    }

    render() {
        const { tabs } = this.props
            , { activeTab } = this.state
        return (
            <div className={`accordion`}>
                {tabs.map((t, i) => {
                    const activeClass = activeTab === i ? `accordion--tab__active` : ''
                    return(
                        <section key={i} className={`accordion--tab ${activeClass}`}>
                            <header className={`accordion--header`}>
                                <h4 className={`accordion--title`}>
                                    <button onClick={() => {this._selectAccordion(i)}}>{t.title}</button>
                                </h4>
                            </header>
                            <div className="accordion--content">
                                {t.title}
                                Content
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
    _selectAccordion = activeTab => {this.setState({activeTab})}
}

export default Accordion
```

and **Accordion.react.test.js**

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Accordion from './components/Accordion'

test('Accordion component', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Accordion name={`Main`}/>)
    expect(component.state('activeTab')).equals(0)
})
```

Comment: The test runs well on my computer, though I have to change `.equals(0)` to `.toEqual(0)`. Maybe you could share more debugging information, like enzyme/node version, or at least paste the full error message - the one you pasted surely is only half the message.

Comment: Did you import REACT in Jsx file?

Comment: Yes I import React in `jsx` file.

Comment: You say `jsx` file, but in Accordian.react.test.js you do `import Accordion from './components/Accordion.js`, which is a `js` file not a `jsx` file. Are you sure the file extension is correct? You shouldn't need to put the file extension in the file path anyway.

Comment: Its a mistake i have fixed it, but on my real project its just `Accordion`

Comment: js or jsx doesn't matter, just set up your webpack loader on both of them. It's not a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests should verify how the component works but not "how to change a state". You need to throw new props into your component and get a result, and the result is expected.

I've tested my components with snapshots

This is an example of my current project

```
describe('<Component />', () => {
  it('Page rendered', () => {
    const rendered = renderComponent({
      ...testProps,
      loadDataList,
      loading: true,
    });

    expect(rendered).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be a this scoping issue. With event handlers in React, you have to bind the event handler in the constructor to "this". Here is some info from React's [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) about it:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined
>   when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions
>   work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without ()
>   after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that
>   method.

```
class Accordion extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            activeTab: 0
        }

        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this._selectAccordion = this._selectAccordion.bind(this);
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        tabs: [{title: 'Status'}, {title: 'Movement'}]
    }

        _selectAccordion(activeTab){
            this.setState({activeTab : activeTab})
        }

    render() {
        const { tabs } = this.props,
        { activeTab } = this.state
        return (
            <div className={`accordion`}>
                {tabs.map((t, i) => {
                    const activeClass = activeTab === i ? `accordion--tab__active` : ''
                    return(
                        <section key={i} className={`accordion--tab ${activeClass}`}>
                            <header className={`accordion--header`}>
                                <h4 className={`accordion--title`}>
                                    <button onClick={() => {this._selectAccordion(i)}}>{t.title}</button>
                                </h4>
                            </header>
                            <div className="accordion--content">
                                {t.title}
                                Content
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: please don't use bind, if you want to bind anything to anywhere use arrow functions. Bind is VERY VERY SLOW, you should know that if you know how V8 works.